# SOLID (SRP) vs performance

Tags: php, eloquent, single-responsibility-principle

I'm trying to improve my code by applying SOLID principles and I don't know what to prioritize, SRP or performance.

The problem involves fetching data from two different sources and then persisting that information in database. This leads me to the next flow:

1. One class to fetch everything from an RSS. This fetching returns an array with the items of the RSS URI. **Then I loop through each item and I create a simple array of POPOs**.
2. Then again I loop this array of POPOs to add additional data which comes from an API call.
3. Finally I've to persist this data. Which may lead (or not if I build a insert multiple) to another loop as I'm using Eloquent which uses Active Record.

The main problem I find with this approach is that I separate concerns at the cost of worse performance (multiple loops). Something that I could solve executing all operations on the first loop.

Some people told me that it's ok as far as performance is not a problem, and is a trade-off that I should accept to keep my code maintenable, but is this the right approach?

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Are you looping through a few hundred elements or are we talking 10.000's? Unless there's _a lot_ of elements your iterating over, I would agree with "some people". There are usually many other things that affect performance more than some loops (unless they are very large).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how expect your program's performance to be impacted? It sounds like you're comparing one loop that does three things vs three loops that does one thing each. Both should result in the same performance.

Comment: @DelenaMalan - Not necessarily. If it's an array with a massive amount of data, then it will be more costly to iterate it multiple times. However, if it isn't that much data, then it would most likely be negligible.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson we're talking about 100 items. The process is reasonably fast. I was worried about what would happen if some day this turns to be 10000 items, but I guess that would be preoptimization, which is not a good thing.

Comment: Worry about code maintenance and readability first and performance last in most applications.   Unless you're writing something low-level, pre-optimization is evil.

Comment: If we're talking 100 - 1000 items, you won't even notice any difference. If those loops becomes an issue, you should probably upgrade the server anyway.